# String cannot be converted to JSONObject?

Tags: java, php, mysql, json, android-emulator

I'm a beginner in developing Android apps and it's the first time I'd be coding from scratch that's why I find it very hard for me. Basically, I just want to get rid of the error so that I can now start with displaying the SQL table on my Android application. I am barred by this error as I was fetching the data from mySQL tables. I am getting this at LogCat:

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
05-03 15:45:25.586: W/System.err(552): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-03 15:45:25.626: W/System.err(552):  at hs.stockapp.StocksTask.doInBackground(StocksTask.java:64)
```

If I understood the error right, something's wrong with line 64 of my StocksTask.java file.

Line 64: `if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null)`

StocksTask.java code excerpt:

```
protected Integer doInBackground(String... params)  {

    UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
    JSONObject json = userFunction.findStocks();
    try {
        if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
            String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

            if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){         
                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(activity.getApplicationContext());
                JSONObject json_stocks = json.getJSONObject("stocks");
                Log.v("company_name", json_stocks.getString(STOCK_COMPANY_NAME));
                userFunction.findStocks();
                db.findStocks(json_stocks.getString(STOCK_COMPANY_NAME), json_stocks.getString(STOCK_SYMBOL), json_stocks.getString(STOCK_MCAP));                        

                responseCode = 1;
                // Close Screen
                //finish();
            }else{
                responseCode = 0;
                // Error 
            }
        }
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responseCode;
}
```

UserFunctions.java

```
 public JSONObject findStocks(){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", findstocks_tag));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(stocksURL, params);
    // return json
    return json;
}
```

index.php

```
else if ($tag == 'stocks'){
    // request type is view stock list
    $stocks = $db->search_stocks();
    if ($stocks != false) {
        // stocks
        // echo json with success = 1
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["stocks"]["company_name"] = $stocks["name"];
        $response["stocks"]["com_sym"] = $stocks["com_sym"];
        $response["stocks"]["mkt_cap"] = $stocks["mkt_cap"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // no stocks found
        // echo json with error = 0
        $response["error"] = 1;
        $response["error_msg"] = "No stocks found";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

}
```

DB_functions.php

```
    public function search_stocks() {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT company_name, com_sym, mkt_cap from stock ORDER BY com_sym") or die(mysql_error());
    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $output[] = $row;
        }               
        print(json_encode($output)); 
        return $row;            
    return true;
    } else {
        // stocks not existed
        return false;
    }
mysql_close();
```

}

Produced result of search_stocks function

```
[{"company_name":"Asian Chorva","com_sym":"ASIA","mkt_cap":"4534356"},{"company_name":"Banko de Oro","com_sym":"BDO","mkt_cap":"54434"},{"company_name":"Bank of the Phil Island","com_sym":"BPI","mkt_cap":"5464554"},{"company_name":"College Hive In Boon","com_sym":"CHIB","mkt_cap":"5434654"},{"company_name":"Critical Heart Throb Racing","com_sym":"CHTR","mkt_cap":"53544564654"}]
```

What should I do with Line 64?? MANY THANKS :) Any help will be greatly appreciated. Additional info about it will be very helpful.

Comment: Your server doesn not seem to respond with JSON, it answers with xml actually.

Comment: Try sending the header('Content-type: json/application') before printing json_encode($output)

Comment: @VladimirIvanov Thank you! I think I've gotten a grip on what the error means now. Now finding out ways on how to resolve it.

Comment: @ChadHedgcock Thanks but that didn't solve the prob :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message says:

> Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

If it is `<!DOCTYPE` then it isn't `[{"company_name":…`.

You need to figure out exactly what request is being made and why the server is returning an HTML document.

Check your server logs. It might be an error document.

Comment: Maybe he's encoding the JSON string but not preventing the server to produce standard HTML with headers and all the stuff...

Comment: @helios Oh! Any suggestions what to do then? Sorry I'm really clueless. Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: @Masochist — Following the directions I gave in my original answer will tell you if helios' speculation is correct or not.

Comment: @Quentin I got it now. Then again, it's the error the proxy produces when I try to access the database. :/ I will try to figure out how I can pass thru it and check if my prob is solved. Thanks!! You guys are huge help.

Answer (score 0):

check your url properly in which you are going to display like  `"http://10.0.2.2/api/"` in UserFunctions.java where  api folder is stored in www or htdocs folder